# Qunit/Chutzpah/$.ajax: doesnt working right. Access Denied

Tags: jquery, qunit, chutzpah

I am having a problem with QUnit. I have several debbugers inside $.ajax in success, complete, ...

the uri is tested in chrome or explorer and it is working but when I execute QUnit test with Chutzpah is not working and doesn't stop in debuggers.

the error returned is: **Access denied**.

I am using: QUNIT, CHUTZPAH, JAVASCRIPT
Navigators: Chrome, Edge, IE

Friend told me something about CORS but I am workingin localhost (127.0.0.1)

Code is:

**test.js:**

```
QUnit.test("UnitTestJS_Query_Builder: testing ajax", function (assert) {    
    // Arrange Test

    var url = "https://127.0.0.1:44321/en/Segmentation/QueryBuilder/EntitySelected";
    var params = {
        ActionType: "1",
        TableCaption: "TEST TABLE",
        ColumnCaption: "TEST COLUMN",
        QueryJson: "SELECT ...",
        OptionsJson: ["1"],
        ConditionIndex: "1"
    }

    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:"GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function () {
            debugger;
            ok(true);
        },
        fail: function () {
            debugger;
            ok(false);
        },
        complete: function () {
            debugger;
        }
    });

    //Asserts
     ok(requests[0].url == url, "uri is OK.")
});
```

**EntitySelected.cs:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EntitySelected(BaseActionModel model)
{
}
```

**the BaseActionModel is:**

```
public class BaseActionModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of the action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The type of the action.
    /// </value>
    public EntityActionType ActionType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the table caption.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The table caption.
    /// </value>
    public string TableCaption { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the column caption.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The column caption.
    /// </value>
    public string ColumnCaption { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the index of the condition.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The index of the condition.
    /// </value>
    public int? ConditionIndex { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the query json.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The query json.
    /// </value>
    public string QueryJson { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the options json.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The options json.
    /// </value>
    public string OptionsJson { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the checkbox values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The checkbox values.
    /// </value>
    public List<string> CheckboxValues { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterless constructor for MVC binding mechanism.
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BaseActionModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public BaseActionModel()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copy constructor.
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BaseActionModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    public BaseActionModel(BaseActionModel model)
    {
        this.ActionType = model.ActionType;
        this.TableCaption = model.TableCaption;
        this.ColumnCaption = model.ColumnCaption;
        this.OptionsJson = model.OptionsJson;
        this.QueryJson = model.QueryJson;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether [is valid action].
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///   <c>true</c> if [is valid action]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.NotImplementedException">still not implemented yet!</exception>
    public virtual bool IsValidAction()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("still not implemented yet!");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the specific action model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static BaseActionModel GetSpecificActionModel(BaseActionModel model)
    {
        BaseActionModel specificModel = null;

        switch (model.ActionType)
        {
            case EntityActionType.EntitySelected:
                specificModel = new EntityActionModel(model);
                break;
            case EntityActionType.ConditionSelected:
                specificModel = new ConditionActionModel(model);
                break;
            case EntityActionType.ValueSelected:
                specificModel = new ValueActionModel(model);
                break;
        }

        return specificModel;
    }
}
```

Could you help me pls?

Comment: How are you executing the tests? Chutzpah in browser or command line? 
What is your chutzpah.json file?
Can you provide a repro?

Comment: The url for your Ajax calls will have to be on the same protocol, domain, and port as the tests themselves. In other words, if you run the tests from `http` then that Ajax call will need to be `http` (not `https`). This is what we mean by "cross origin".